# finding key from given ciphertext and open text

Tags: rc4

very new to crypto-stuff, i have to write a program in C that compute key(k) used in RC4 when I know open text(p) and ciphered(c) text

so I have `c_1=p_1 XOR k`. How do I compute key from this? What is the "inverse" operation to XOR ?

Comment: XOR is the inverse of XOR.

Comment: so i do p xor c = k ? or c xor p = k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're given $c,p$ and are challenged to find $k$ using the relation $c=p\oplus k$ (where $\oplus$ denotes bit-wise XOR).

As the inverse operation of XOR is, well, XOR, you can recover $k$ by computing $k=p\oplus c=c\oplus p$.

---

You may be wondering a) why is XOR the inverse of XOR and b) why is XOR commutative (e.g. $a\oplus b=b\oplus a$).

For b), we need the truth table of XOR:

```
Input 1 | Input 2 | Output
--------+---------+-------
   0    |    0    |   0   
--------+---------+-------
   0    |    1    |   1   
--------+---------+-------
   1    |    0    |   1   
--------+---------+-------
   1    |    1    |   0
```

and you can clearly see, that XOR is commutative, as the same input always results in a "1" and a different input (no matter where it comes from) always results in a "0".

As for a), we need to see that $c\oplus p = k \oplus p \oplus p = k$, e.g. that $a\oplus a=0$ and that $a\oplus 0=a$ which is trivial to see given the above truth table, as you can clealy observe that the same input bit always results in a zero and any input always results in itself if paired with a zero.